# Encrypted string is not the same as test vector

Tags: c, openssl, aes

So I am trying to encrypt some data with the EVP-API from OpenSSL. But I am not recieving the same result as the test vectors.

This is the main function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <openssl\aes.h>
#include <openssl\evp.h>

int main()
{

    unsigned char *to = (unsigned char*)malloc(2056);
    ZeroMemory(to,2056);
    int *tosize;
    unsigned char* key = (unsigned char*)"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
    unsigned char* iv = (unsigned char*)"00000000000000000000000000000000";
    unsigned char* plain = (unsigned char*)"00000000000000000000000000000000";
    to = AESEncrypt(key,iv,plain,strlen((const char*)plain));
    if (to != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen((const char*)to);i++)
        {
            printf("%x02", (int*)UCHAR(to[i]));
        }

    }
}
```

And this is the function which I am trying to call. No errors recieved. Every call is true (no error).

```
 unsigned char* AESEncrypt(unsigned char* key, unsigned char*iv, unsigned char*plain, size_t plainsize)
{

EVP_CIPHER_CTX *x = (EVP_CIPHER_CTX*) malloc(sizeof(EVP_CIPHER_CTX));
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(x);
if (EVP_EncryptInit(x,EVP_aes_256_cbc(),key,iv))
{
    unsigned char* to = (unsigned char*) malloc(plainsize + EVP_CIPHER_CTX_block_size(x));
int tosize = 0;

if(EVP_EncryptUpdate(x,to,&tosize,plain,plainsize))
{
    if (EVP_EncryptFinal(x,to,&tosize))
    {
        return to;
    }   
  }
}

return 0;
}
```

This is the test vector:

```
KEY = 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
IV = 00000000000000000000000000000000
PLAINTEXT = 80000000000000000000000000000000
CIPHERTEXT = ddc6bf790c15760d8d9aeb6f9a75fd4e
```

This is what I am recieving:
    CIPHERTEXT = 5a0215028e.... and it goes on. As you see it is not correct.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: You must not mutate string literals. Make your pointers into pointers-to-const.

Comment: OT: How is `to` being passed into your encryption function? Or is that just there to test this in the confines of a memory leak?

Comment: `to` is where the output goes.

Comment: So is this your first rodeo with implementing a CAVS harness? Just curious, because your data is NOT correct. Unless someone beats me to it I'll post details for why in an answer.

Comment: Yeah, this is the first time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CAVS test vectors follow a fairly straight-forward pattern. From test to test they vary to certain degrees, but one thing is eminently consistent:

**Hex Strings are BYTE representations; NOT character data**

Hence your "test" is entirely wrong. You're using a key, iv, and plain text that is filled with the character '0', not the **byte** value **0**. So obviously no wonder you're getting a different result.

For *that specific* test your arrays should be:

```
unsigned char key[64] = {0};
unsigned char iv[16] = {0};
unsigned char plain[16] = {0};
```

Furthermore, your size sent to your encryption function should be the *byte count* of your plain text. Finally, your encryption function should ideally take a target buffer AND a modifiable size as the output parameters.

```
int AESEncrypt256(
    unsigned char* key,      // key must be 64 bytes wide.
    unsigned char *iv,       // IV must be 16 bytes wide.
    unsigned char *src,      // source buffer to encryt
    unsigned int src_len,    // length of source buffer in bytes
    unsigned char *dst,      // target buffer to write to
    unsigned int *dst_len);  // in: size of dst, out: bytes written to dst
```

And code the function to match those parameters. You'll be glad you did.

CAVS tests vectors are not "text". They are **bytes** and should be treated as such. You need to get a handle on that now, as the Monte Carlo tests are likely going to cost you some hair if you don't.

Do yourself an **enormous** favor and write some code **now** that translates a string of hex digits into an `unsigned char` byte array. You'll need the same to translate back for result strings. And make these routines **solid** as you will be using them a *lot* when writing these tests.

---

**Spoiler Alert**

Test the string for an odd number of chars *first*. If it is odd, the first byte in your translated buffer should be based on `0c`, where `c` is the first `char` in the input string. From then on (or if the number of chars is even, then from the very start) grab them two-at-a-time when converting the rest of the byte string into real bytes. This means this

```
123456
```

results in a byte array of

```
{ 0x12, 0x34, 0x56 }
```

while this:

```
89AB1
```

should be:

```
{0x08, 0x9A, 0xB1 }
```

Comment: @owlstead I feel his pain. It is just ugly grunt work writing all those meticulous tests, I especially hated the TDES MC tests. Ugh. Come to think of it, I abstracted the whole thing into a plug-in-your-crypto-lib template library. Maybe I should market that thing... LOL =P

Comment: Yeah, I created a tool which converts between UTF-8, UTF-16, UltraEdit hex code, Java hex bytes, Java debugger bytes, C++ bytes, character arrays etc. etc. just for this reason. Without that you get too many mistakes when copying the test vectors :)

Comment: @owlstead You actually incorporated your vectors? Ours just read straight from the source tree on disk. You'd point it at a root folder that contains all the vectors, run it, and it generates all the resp folders and the files for each test within said-same. And yeah, `cavs_string` (based on `std::string`) and `cavs_bytes` (based on `std::vector<uint8_t>`) and a nice family of functions and operators to flip from one to the other. Came in *damn* handy.

Comment: Other test vectors ECC mostly, hence the copying.